# How to call WebService using AJAX if I created ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

How to call WebService (using AJAX) if I created ASP.NET Web Application template. Every where people are telling how to call web service if you have created a WebSite template in visual studio but not about ASP.NET Web Application template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great link that walks through all the steps: [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)